# How to extract 4th line from 300 text files?

Tags: email, gmail

I have about 300 emails (gmail) that go like this:

> Dear [name]
>
> Order ID:123456789
>   Purchased by: [name I need]
>
> (blah blah another 26 lines of crap (total of 30 lines))

What I need help is how to save gmail's mails locally into .txt and how to export 4th line from each text file. I can easily run Replace 'Purchased by: ' to remove that and keep only the names from that line in a list, but other than that I have no clue

Any ideas?

Comment: What system do you want this to run on?

Comment: Use Google's data tools to export the mails into the MBOX format, then use `grep -e 'Order ID:\d* Purchased by'` and `sed 's/Order ID:\d+ Purchased by:\s+//'` to extract the names.

Comment: Windows 7, I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 1):

Export the gmail messages in MBOX format (hint: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024195?hl=en) and save them as messages.txt

Grab GNU Awk (gawk.exe) from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm

Save the following as getnames.awk:

```
/^Order ID:.*Purchased by:/ {
  sub("^.+ by: ","");
  print;
}
```

Save the following as names2csv.awk:

```
/^Order ID:.*Purchased by:/ {
  sub("^.*Order ID:[^0-9]*","");
  sub("[^0-9]*Purchased by: ",",");
  print;
}
```

Now that you've got the scripts and messages above, this will get you a list of names as a text file:

```
gawk -f getnames.awk messages.txt > names.txt
```

And this will get you order IDs and names as a .CSV file, suitable for opening in your favorite spreadsheet software:

```
gawk -f names2csv.awk messages.txt > orders.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract Data directly from Gmail, parse it and save it to an Excel sheet or to other formats like XML, CSV using MsgExtract.

[image]

[image]

In your case you should define a TextPart field and use the following regular expression to extract only the name, between the brackets []:

(?s)(?<=(by:.[)).+(?=])

If for instance you want to get the text: “Purchased by: [name I need]” use the following expression:

(?s)Purchased.+]

You can learn more about Regular Expressions in MsgExtract at the following link:

http://docs.maildev.com/article/69-parse-email-data-using-regular-expressions

http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)